# Can Cassandra perform incremental backup and full backup alternately?

Tags: cassandra, database-backups

Cassandra supports incremental backups by setting cassandra.yaml. But how if I want doing the full backup after set incremental backup to true? Is there a way to running full backup without shutdown or restart the cassandra server?

What i mean is, for example, full backup on the first day of each month, and incremental backup everyday and the service can not be suspend.

Can this situation being perform?

Comment: Can you explain your Cassandra Architecture , for eg: are you using DAS or SAN or NAS for storage?

Comment: None of above, I install C* on EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

Full backups are performed by running `nodetool snapshot` on every node in the cluster.  This will flush all memtables to disk and create hard links to the SSTables.  The incremental backup feature that retains copies of commit log files is only useful if you have snapshots.

From the [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsAboutSnapshots.html) for snapshots:

> After a system-wide snapshot is performed, you can enable incremental backups
>   on each node to backup data that has changed since the last snapshot

and [restoring](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsBackupSnapshotRestore.html).

> Restoring a keyspace from a snapshot requires all snapshot files for
>   the table, and if using incremental backups, any incremental backup
>   files created after the snapshot was taken.

Comment: although all is true, but this not answer to the question, which was: after having already snapshot1 + a series of incremental bacups in the snapshots and backup folder respectively, what are the steps to perform a snapshot2 (besides of nodetool snaoshot...) for example exactly when to delete the ubbecessary incremental backup files, and how to know which one is unnecessary...